# Meteor's Iron Router - Alter Path before routing

Tags: javascript, url, meteor, path, iron-router

Is there a way to change the path before the page is routed based on some logic, such as a `Session` variable? For example:

```
// Before routing
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    if(Session.get('key') === true) {
        prependToPath('prefix');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current path using `Iron.Location.get().path`, run through your logic, and then use the new path in `Router.go()`. Like so:

```
// If abc is set on the URL, then keep it there
if (Session.get('abc') === true) { // You can use better logic here
    Router.go('/abc' + Iron.Location.get().path);
}
```

and make sure you `Session.set('abc') = false` somewhere or else it will keep on looping, adding `/abc` in an infinite loop.